# i am getting some input from html forms ,i have to set the firebase child name according to input

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am new to firebase.I have one slight confusion I am getting input some data in from the html forms and i have to set the child name according to that.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to this.

```
dataBase.push({
    'name': document.getElementById('name').value,
    'Email': document.getElementById('email').value,
    'Phone number': document.getElementById('phonenumber').value
});
```